# R is a reflection across a plane through the origin if and only if the following 3 conditions hold.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $R: R^{3} \rightarrow R^{3}$ be a linear operator. Thne R is a reflection across a plan $\Pi$ through the origin iff the following three conditions hold:

1) R has a 1-dimensional eigenspace U with eigenvalue -1

2) R has a 2-dimensional eigenspace W with eigenvalue 1

3) U $\bot$ W

I'm not sure where to start here. I have taken time off from school and have been reviewing linear algebra and algebra but am still confused. *I'm not looking for an answer, but the thought process to take.* Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: What is your definition of a reflection?